# How to sort my list by descending numbers and ascending alphabet?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list of lists

```
l = [[2, 'Horror'], [2, 'Romance'], [2, 'Comedy'], [3, 'Action'], [1, 'Adventure'], [2, 'History']]
```

and want this output that sort first by numbers in descending order and then by alphabet in ascending order:

```
[[3, 'Action'], [2, 'Comedy'], [2, 'History'], [2, 'Horror'], [2, 'Romance'], [1, 'Adventure']]
```

but I receive this using `sorted(l, reverse=True)`:

```
[[3, 'Action'], [2, 'Romance'], [2, 'Horror'], [2, 'History'], [2, 'Comedy'], [1, 'Adventure']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can sort using a lambda function:

```py
lst = [[2, 'Horror'], [2, 'Romance'], [2, 'Comedy'], [3, 'Action'], [1, 'Adventure'], [2, 'History']]
output = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
print(output)

# [[3, 'Action'], [2, 'Comedy'], [2, 'History'], [2, 'Horror'], [2, 'Romance'], [1, 'Adventure']]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can sort like this,

test_list = ["1", "G", "7", "L", "9", "M", "4"]

print("The original list is : " + str(test_list))

numerics = []

alphabets = []

for sub in test_list:

```
if sub.isnumeric():

    numerics.append(sub)
else:
    alphabets.append(sub)
```

res = sorted(alphabets) + sorted(numerics)

print("The Custom sorted result : " + str(res))

Comment: Did you accidentally post this answer on the wrong question, because your answer makes no sense for this question. Also, please read [formatting help](/help/formatting) to see how you can format your code, and from [answer], your answer would be better if you provided some explanation instead of just dumping code.